# Where are the docs for Rails "script/generate model"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptgenerate

I am running

```
ruby script/generate scaffold
```

or

```
ruby script/generate model
```

and I know the basic syntax, like

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Dude name:string face:boolean
```

but I do not know things like:

- should names of variables have underscores or be camelCased?
- what kind of variable types are acceptable?

Where can I find such information?

Comment: Note: With Rails 3 a lot of the old information is out-of-date. Current information about the script generators is at [A Guide to The Rails Command Line -> rails generate](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate)

Comment: thanks @Greg, gotta get my Rails 3 on now.

Comment: Rails 3 is a nice improvement. It's still a steep learning curve but it's not as bad as it once was.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Type the command without arguments and the documentation is revealed:

```
$ script/generate model
```

You can use either camelcase or underscores for the model name.

- Model names are singular; controller names are plural.
- Field names use underscores.

I can't remember all the possible field types, I just look them up from the Migration docs, as linked above.

Answer (score 10):

This document on [Rails Migration](http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations) would help.

With respect to the naming convention, I think the general adopted convention for Ruby on Rails is to have underscores.

To know which variable types are acceptable, refer to the section on [Database Mapping](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/migrations/).

Answer (score 6):

There is a resource on the rails wiki as a [List of Available Generators](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/availablegenerators).

Answer (score 3):

To check Rails naming conventions, topfunky's [Pluralizer](http://nubyonrails.com/tools/pluralize) was useful.

Answer (score 2):

there is a new syntaxis for Rails is `rails generate`